# Blocking internal access from wireless router linksys

Tags: wifi

i have all my access points(ubiquity) connected in another lan independant from my internal lan,by hardware using another switch.
However i have one router in a particular zone that must have access to a internal network printer.
First Question: how do i block users connecting to my internal network and shares and still permiting to print with their laptops wirelessly.
Internal Lan: 192.168.15
Wifi lan: 192.168.10.0
Secont question: Is it possible to let users from network 192.168.10.x have access to only the printer on network 192.168.15.x
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe try to configure access lists on your access points (though I'm not sure if and how this is possible on your devices). Another possibility is to configure access lists on both the internal network and the access point switches.

Best option would be to place a firewall between those two networks, configure a zone for the wifi segment and one for the internal segment and add the necessary policies